# Horizontal scrollbar updating

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt

I was messing around with SWT (for a PropertyPage), and found a little 'bug'?
Basically, when I resize the shell so it is smaller than my controls, it will make a scrollBar visible, which works just as intended. Though if I resize my controls (which are all children of a single root of course), somehow one or more parents don't get updated of the change which results in some weird behavior.

When my controls grow in size, it basically grows out of the shell (not visible) while there is no Scrollbar made visible. If I resize the shell (smaller than the initial size), the ScrollBar will become visible, but only for the initial size instead of the full width.

When my controls shrink in size it won't 'pack' either parent, which means I can scroll beyond the reach of my controls into emptiness.

*Maybe it's worth mentioning that for me only horizontal growing/shrinking is a problem, although I'm pretty sure the same problems are occurring for vertical resizing*

My question was if there is a solution/workaround for this. I have tried calling `Layout()` and `pack()` on various parents and the shell itself, without success. Now I know there is a custom (sadly private) Layout type used by one of the parents of a property page (the `PreferenceDialog#PageLayout`). Maybe this behavior comes this implementation?

**EDIT:** on request an MCVE

I assume one knows how to setup for a propertyPage, so for the sake of clarity I have posted only the createContents method (overriden from `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage`), and a few helper methods/fields which should recreate a setup where this behavior can be observed. Basically play around with hiding/unhiding columns, and make sure to re-open when you want a different initial childSize (to test both growing and shrinking)

```
// static so you can re-open a the property/preference page for different initial sizes.
private static boolean  h1  = false;
private static boolean  h2  = false;
private static boolean  h3  = false;
private static boolean  h4  = false;

private Composite root;

@Override
protected Control createContents(Composite parent)
{
    // setup root
    this.root = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    this.root.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    this.root.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.BEGINNING, false, false));

    Table table = new Table(this.root, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.VIRTUAL | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.BEGINNING, false, false));

    TableColumn c1 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    c1.setMoveable(true);
    c1.setText("column 1");
    this.updateColumn(c1, h1);
    TableColumn c2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    c2.setMoveable(true);
    c2.setText("column 2");
    this.updateColumn(c2, h2);
    TableColumn c3 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    c3.setMoveable(true);
    c3.setText("column 3");
    this.updateColumn(c3, h3);
    TableColumn c4 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.LEFT);
    c4.setMoveable(true);
    c4.setText("column 4");
    this.updateColumn(c4, h4);

    Button hide1 = new Button(this.root, SWT.PUSH);
    hide1.setText("Hide column 1");
    hide1.addListener(SWT.Selection, E -> {
        this.updateColumn(c1, h1 = !h1);
        this.resize();
    });

    Button hide2 = new Button(this.root, SWT.PUSH);
    hide2.setText("Hide column 2");
    hide2.addListener(SWT.Selection, E -> {
        this.updateColumn(c2, h2 = !h2);
        this.resize();
    });

    Button hide3 = new Button(this.root, SWT.NONE);
    hide3.setText("Hide column 3");
    hide3.addListener(SWT.Selection, E -> {
        this.updateColumn(c3, h3 = !h3);
        this.resize();
    });
    Button hide4 = new Button(this.root, SWT.PUSH);
    hide4.setText("Hide column 4");
    hide4.addListener(SWT.Selection, E -> {
        this.updateColumn(c4, h4 = !h4);
        this.resize();
    });

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        TableItem ti = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
        ti.setText(new String[] {"c1:" + i, "c2:" + i, "c3" + i, "c4" + i});
    }

    return root;
}

protected void updateColumn(TableColumn c, boolean hide)
{
    if(hide)
    {
        c.setResizable(false);
        c.setWidth(0);
    }
    else
    {
        c.setResizable(true);
        c.setWidth(300);
    }
}

protected void resize()
{
    this.root.getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> this.root.getShell().layout(null, SWT.ALL | SWT.CHANGED));
}
```

Comment: Show us an [mcve]

Comment: @greg-449 Thought it was pretty straight foreward..., but oke. Working on it

Comment: @greg-449 added an MCVE